# How to read command line arguments of another process in C#?

Tags: c#, process, diagnostics

How can I obtain the command line arguments of another process?

Using static functions of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class I can obtain a list of running processes, e.g. by name:

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
```

However, there is no way to access the command line used to start this process. How would one do that?

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do this for? It might help get a better solution.

Comment: I want to retrieve the command line arguments to find the correct instance of an application, in my case msiexec.

Comment: The link above is now broken. This is the new url: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> If you did not use the Start method to start a process, the StartInfo property does not reflect the parameters used to start the process. For example, if you use GetProcesses to get an array of processes running on the computer, the StartInfo property of each Process does not contain the original file name or arguments used to start the process. (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx))

Stuart's WMI suggestion is a good one:

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", processName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", retObject["CommandLine"]);
```

Comment: You should dispose the objects.

Comment: note that specifically the returned CommandLine will be null if the process that is running the above code runs under unpriviledged account, like in my case (service running as LocalService)

Comment: CommandLine returns full path of the executable. May be this is an issue under Windows7. I didi not test under XP.

Comment: Works for me with Win 7 SP1 x64.  I had Admin priv's.

Comment: namespace System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher, located in System.Management.dll

Comment: Be careful that for the sample code to work you need admin privileges

Answer (score 5):

If you're targeting Windows XP or later and you can afford the overhead of WMI, a possibility would be to look up the target process using WMI's [WIN32_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx), which has a CommandLine property.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.StartInfo` returns a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_members.aspx) object that allegedly but not necessarily has the arguments in the Arguments property.

Comment: It hasn't in my case :( Could be that this only works if the other process is hosted in the CLR.

Comment: In fact, the Arguments property is only set if the process was started from a managed process using a ProcessStartInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

Are both projects yours?  Could you modify the source for the process you're trying to examine to make it give you its command-line arguments, rather than trying to read them from somewhere outside of that process?

Comment: Nope, the other process is Microsoft's msiexec

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Process class.

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    public static string GetCommandLine(this Process process)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + process.Id))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection objects = searcher.Get())
                {
                    return objects.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().SingleOrDefault()?["CommandLine"]?.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```