# WMI and getting CommandLine of running Process in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, command-line, wmi

This is the command line I want to use inside my VB.NET program. Look for the running process "mpc-hc.exe" and get the commandline of the running process

```
wmic process where name='mpc-hc.exe' get CommandLine
```

I want to retrieve the output from that command into a string. I know that it could be done natively in a VB.NET program and I have looked at how it was done. However, I cannot get the code to perform what it did in the commandline I have above.

Any suggestions on how should I implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504208/how-to-read-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wmic` is a command-line wrapper for **Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)** API. In .NET Framework, the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace provides access to this API.

The Visual Basic .NET equivalent of your command line is below. This code queries the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class instances corresponding to *mpc-hc.exe* and reads their `CommandLine` property:

```
Imports System.Management
...

Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
  "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='mpc-hc.exe'")

For Each process As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()
  Console.WriteLine(process("CommandLine"))
Next
```