# List all USB audio headsets connected to a Windows PC

Tags: c#, windows

I want to use C# to retrieve the USB headset devices connected to PC. I tried the below solutions but didn't work:

**Solution 1:**
[How to enumerate audio out devices in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525320/how-to-enumerate-audio-out-devices-in-c-sharp?lq=1)

I tried this but the device name appears as "(Generic USB Audio)" and not the actual name.

**Solution 2:**
[How to get the default audio device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611573/how-to-get-the-default-audio-device)

**Solution 3:**
[Detecting Audio Input & output devices connected to system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936434/detecting-audio-input-output-devices-connected-to-system)

Solution 2 and Solution 3 gave me the below result:
*The device name is truncated to 31 characters.*
Eg: "Microphone (Sennheiser VOICE 689"

[image]

****Question: Is there any way I can get the complete name of the device?****

Comment: Are you shure that Solution 1 gives you only one device. I tested it on my machine and it returns 2 devices. First one is "(Generic USB Audio)" and second looks like "real one" I have

Comment: It gives multiple devices. For headset it appears like this "(Generic USB Audio)"

Comment: @JohnSaunders: You're doing it badly, though.  Convert tag lists into real phrases using the tags, please.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251859/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry, disagree in this case. The vast majority of any answers have nothing to do with C#, and the tag adequately informs those who answer that they should answer in C#.

Comment: @John:there's no C# in the title. Was briefly while I thought about which words would really describe the problem accurately.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that's kind of my point. I took a "C#" out of the title, where it represented "metadata" (tags), not "data"  (title).

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Ahh, sorry.  I saw other, more useful content removed from the title, and didn't realize that was the OP changing it in response to your comment, and not your change.

Comment: By "complete name" do you mean the "friendly name" of the audio endpoint? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24220881/67824

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's an USB audio device, and assuming the driver is correctly written for the device, you could do:

```
foreach (ManagementObject drive in
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "select Name from Win32_USBDevice where Service='usbaudio'").Get())
{
    {
        string s = drive["Name"].ToString();
        // Continue
    }
}
```

**Addition**
You're only getting 31 characters (technically 32) because the PInvoke to the native .DLLs use a char[32], so it can't return more than that; you won't get what you need from solution 1 & 2.

Also, I don't know why you can't use Win32_USBDevice, as I'm also using Win7 x64 and I'm having no problems.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918265/c-sharp-invalid-class-in-a-simple-wmi-query) link might help you.

**Possible Alternate**
You might be able to use the `Win32_PnPEntity` class:

```
foreach (ManagementObject drive in
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "select Name from Win32_PnPEntity where Service='usbaudio'").Get())
{
    {
        string s = drive["Name"].ToString();
        // Continue.  Can look at Description, Caption, etc. too
    }
}
```

Comment: (ManagementObject drive in
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                    "select Name from Win32_USBHub").Get())
            {
                {
                    string s = drive["Name"].ToString();
                }
            }   This is gave me "Generic USB Hub" and not the actual name

Comment: I am using windows 7. Solution 2 and 3 gave me the actual name but the string was truncated to 31 characters.

Comment: I could not resolve the Win32_USBDevice issue. I tried the solution provided in the link but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried that as well but didn't work. I installed WMI code creator and tried few classes but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried it on other machines because that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I will check tomorrow.