# Wait for a process to start, then capture the command line arguments that were provided to it

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if this can be done at all, but if it can, what's the simplest way to do it?

I basically want my program to wait until it notices that a process that I want tracked has started up. Then I want to get the arguments that were passed to it.

I have a guarantee that the process will always start with some arguments passed to it.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504208/how-to-read-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-c

Comment: Oh... Very sorry guys. Should have searched better.