# I cannot retrieve process arguments using ProcessStartInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, process, command-line-arguments, processstartinfo

I want to detect whether a process with a certain name and also specific command line arguments is already running. I use `Process.GetProcessesByName` to get the list of processes and tried to check the argument field of each processes `StartInfo` property - it's always empty. Why?

I tried starting with administrative rights.
I worked around the issue by using a WMI query eventually, but am not satisfied ...

Answer (score 1):

As Steve commented, this is a possible duplicate. But to respond here, the Process.StartInfo will only work if you have launched the application this way. WMI will be the only way yo go I think via the the other solution:

[How to read command line arguments of another process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504208/how-to-read-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-c)

Why was the WMI solution not satisfying?

Good Luck.

Comment: It was not satisfying because I didn't understand why the original idea was not working - now I do and am satisfied

Comment: no problem - if this (or any other answer that might come up) answers the question for you, don't forget to accept the answer.