# Differentiating between processes with the same name outside of my application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a WPF application in C# that will monitor the processes running on a machine. I want to be able to collect a list of currently running processes and compare them to a list of processes I want to run. If the process I want to run is not yet running, then my application will start it.

I am having a problem getting the processes by name because I have numerous processes running off of one parent application (they are all started with different executable parameters,) so they all have the same process name. I also can't use process ID because there is no way for me to know the PID of processes started outside of my application. I need some way to differentiate the processes from one another both started in and outside of my application so that I can tell if they are already running. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the command path

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you include the code of your attempt so far?

Comment: But you can read their command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504208/how-to-read-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-c/504378%23504378

Comment: `I have numerous processes running off of one parent application (they are all started with different executable parameters) so they all have the same process name.` is the parent application your own? Or is it a third-party application?

Comment: the parent application is a massive third party app. I am currently interning at a company so i am not allowed to post the code. I realize thats hard to work with but i was just wondering if i could differentiate between the processes by checking something other than the name. I will look into checking their command lines, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/504378/122195), you can query the command-line parameters of a process with [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx), by doing the following, for example if you have the ProcessId:

```
var wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where ProcessId='{0}'", processId);
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
var retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", retObject["CommandLine"]);
```

You can probably use a similar query to [Win32_Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) to find all the ProcessId with the same ProcessName.

Answer (score -1):

Try by doing below to find all process in a local machine.

```
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=VS.110).aspx